# Always set "reply-to" for certain recipients?

Tags: thunderbird

Is it possible to always have Thunderbird set "reply-to" for a certain set of recipients?  I sometimes email my significant other at work (about upcoming office parties, events, etc. that she would need to know about), but I'd like to handle the rest of the discussion from my personal email account.

Answer (score 1):

Would [**Reply to Mailing list**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/4455) solve your issue?

> Adds a "reply to mailing list" button
>   to your toolbar and the message menu.
>   Pressing it will open an email reply
>   window with only one single "To:"
>   address set: The mailing list address.

[image]

[Though this feature should](http://alumnit.ca/wiki/index.php?page=ReplyToListThunderbirdExtension) be implemented into Thunderbird 3

[image]